# Need some insights on 'index_page' variables in Innodb_Metrics Table

Tags: mysql, innodb, insert, data-pages, page-splits

I was experimenting with page-split behaviour for sequencial vs random ordered inserts in Mysql,Innodb.

For sequencial Inserts I got:

```
index_page_splits:           3199
index_page_merge_attempts:   0
index_page_merge_successful: 0
index_page_reorg_attempts:   0
index_page_reorg_successful: 0
```

For random Inserts I got:

```
index_page_splits:           4423
index_page_merge_attempts:   1
index_page_merge_successful: 1
index_page_reorg_attempts:   1
index_page_reorg_successful: 1
```

I am having two questions:

1.Why there are increments in **index_page_merge_attempts**,**index_page_merge_successful**,
**index_page_reorg_attempts**,**index_page_reorg_successful** variables?

2.What is the difference between **attempts** and **successfull** variables?

Comment: if you are read this question, please comment here if you need further information from my side.

Answer (score 1):

How big are the rows?  I'm surprised that the "splits" numbers are similar.

"Merge" probably refers to what *may* happen after `DELETEing` a row or `UPDATEing` a row such that the row is smaller.  The block contains less.  If that shrunken block is next to another block that is also rather shrunken, then it behooves InnoDB to "merge" the two blocks together.  This won't happen if all you are doing is `INSERTs`.

"Attempts" vs "Successful" -- Suppose some row is locked.  Or something else is going on that would be disrupted by the "merge".  It would be better to abort the merge, than to mess up the 'real' operation.

What is the typical size of the `TEXT` column?  It could be stored in the row, or it could be stored elsewhere.  The "merges" could be happening in the off-record storage.

Comment: I got "Merge" attempts during inserts also. I will re-run the case and let it know here.

Comment: I also came across "Merges" during inserts in another case (inserted in random order). But I am guessing that 'Merges' happens during 'Random' inserts. Because, in the same case , during ordered inserts no 'merge' happens

Comment: To answer you question 'How big are the rows?' , only two column, one pk and one text.. You question also rise a discussion that 'splits' also relates to row size...

Comment: I added some more.  Oh, is there a `FULLTEXT` index?

Comment: Nope there are no fulltext indexes..